# Sorting sections of text (unix/shell)

Tags: bash, unix, sorting

I have some data sets (`foo`) with `bar` and `baz` as output in sections'. Sections with `baz` should be sorted to be at the top of the output.

Example input;

```
= foo4 =
bar
(..)
barN
= foo1 =
bar
(..)
barN
= foo5 =
bar
(..)
barN
baz
= foo2 =
bar
(..)
barN
= foo3 =
bar
(..)
barN
baz
```

In above example, I would like section `= foo3 =` and `= foo5 =` to be moved to the top of the output, and have the list sub-sorted by section "name", ie.

```
= foo3 =
= foo5 =
= foo1 =
= foo2 =
= foo4 =
```

but with the contents of the section intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution. It uses a hash of sections, the key is the name of a section, the value contains the position in the file where the section starts and the information whether `baz` was present. Once the file is read into the hash, the keys are sorted and the contents is printed, moving around the file as remembered.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = shift;

my $start = qr/^= (.*) =$/;

open my $FH, '<', $file or die $!;

my %sections;
my $current_section;
while (<$FH>) {
    if (/$start/) {
        $current_section = $1;
        $sections{$current_section}{begin} = tell $FH;
    } elsif (/baz/) {
        $sections{$current_section}{baz} = 1;
    }
}

for my $section (map substr( $_, 1),
                 sort map { ($sections{$_}{baz} ? '0' : '1') . $_ }
                 keys %sections) {
    seek $FH, $sections{$section}{begin}, 0;
    print "= $section =\n";
    while (<$FH>) {
        last if /$start/;
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works completely as advertised, was a quick and easily legible answer. Would and will read again A++.

Comment: As an aside, I also have "dead"/empty sections - can I discard those with another `elsif`?

Comment: @Jan: Well, empty sections would go through the first `if` branch. You can set a section to nonempty once it contains anything, i.e. even before checking `/baz/`. You can skip seeking the empty sections when outputting.

Answer (score 2):

Lottastuff solution, a.k.a., *fat-oneliner*:

```
awk '/^=/{print ""} {printf "%s\t", $0}' input.txt | \
    awk '{print ($NF != "baz")"\t"$0}' | sort -n | cut -f 2- | \
    tr '\t' '\n' | sed -e '/^$/d'
```

The initial transformation is darn too picky. There should be some tool capable of *pasting lines until delimiter* (:

Comment: I had considered a similar approach, but it just seemed too damned *messy* in the end. Thank you for taking the time to suggest it, though :)